# Combination: choose 3 different numbers from a set

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> What is the number of ways to choose $3$ different numbers from the set $S=\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 15\}$ such that the product of the $3$ numbers is even? divisible by $4$?

My solution for the first question is $\binom{7}{1}\binom{14}{2}$. Not sure if it's correct.

Comment: It's not right, because you have double counting.  You count choose $2$ and then choose $3$ and $4$ as different from choose $4$ and then choose $2$ and $3$, but in both cases you choose $2,3,4$.

Comment: I see what you mean, but not sure how to solve this. Can you give a hint?

Comment: Would (7 choose 1)(8 choose 2)+(7 choose 2)(8 choose 1)+(7 choose 3) work?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The easiest way to do the first part is to work from the opposite direction.  It's a lot easier to count the total number of ways to choose three numbers, and then to count the ways to choose them such that the product is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A number n is divisble by another number k if the multiset of prime factors of k is a subset of the multiset of prime factors of n.

Hence, for you product to be divisble by 3 take some number in S which is divisble by 3 and add any other two other numbers from S. Think about how many numbers in S are divisble by three and how many options you have to choose the other two factors (take care to count combinations with two or three factors which are divisble by 3 only once).

The approach for 4 and 9 is really similar, just a few more case distinctions (consider factors divisble by 2 respectively 3 and take care to have those prime factors appear twice).

Answer (score 1):

As saulspatz pointed out in the comments, your original attempt is incorrect since it counts each outcome in which more than one even number is selected multiple times.  In particular, it counts those selections with two even numbers twice, once for each way you could designate one of the selected even numbers as the even number you are selecting, and those selections with three even numbers three times.

Your revised answer in the comments
$$\binom{7}{1}\binom{8}{2} + \binom{7}{2}\binom{8}{1} + \binom{7}{3}$$
is correct.

As lulu pointed out in the comments, any product of integers is even except those containing only odd factors.  Thus, we can find the answer by subtracting the number of ways of selecting three odd numbers from the number of selecting three numbers from the set, which yields
$$\binom{15}{3} - \binom{8}{3}$$

As for the second problem, any selection that includes $4$, $8$, or $12$ will have a product divisible by $4$.  You can also obtain a product that is divisible by $4$ by including at least two of the other four even numbers.  You will have to be careful not to count the same selection more than once.